# serialize Ext.data.JsonStore content

Tags: serialization, extjs

How do you serialize the JsonStore content? I tried Ext.encode(store.data.items), but it throws an exception "too many recursions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick function that should work

```
function(store) {
    if(typeof(store) != 'object') { return ''; }
    var dataArray = [];
    var encodedData = '';
    var data = store.data.items;
    Ext.each(data, function(item, index, array) {
        dataArray.push(item.data); 
    });
    return Ext.encode(dataArray);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that uses the `each()` function on the store itself.

```
function getEncodedStoreItems(storeName) {
    var encodedData = "";
    if (typeof storeName !== "undefined") {
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(storeName);
        if (store != null) {
            var data = [];
            store.each(function(item, index, count) {
                data.push(item.data);
            });
            encodedData = Ext.encode(data);
        }
    }
    return encodedData;
}
```